# Problem matching data in tables using regex

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Here, I want to update categoryName for image2 wherever characters in **categoryID (image2)** matches with **categorID (image1)**. however, I want for categoryID **"AA BB"(image2)** should have category name updated as Archeology, Business. But , I am not getting the desired result with the query that I have pasted here.

[image]

[image: enter image here]

```
UPDATE image2 INNER JOIN [image1] ON image2.CategoryID = image1.CategoryID SET image2.CategoryName = image1.CategoryName
WHERE ((([image1].CategoryID) Like "*[A-Z\s]*"));
```

Comment: Instead of `LIKE` try using `REGEXP_LIKE(column, regex)`, e.g. `REGEXP_LIKE([image1].CategoryID, '*[A-Z\s]*)`

Comment: @Nikola this is giving me "undefined function" error. Also, tried with RegexMatch. However, getting the same error. I am working on ms-access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Image1 TABLE (CategoryID varchar(2), CategoryName varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Image1
    VALUES
            ('AA', 'Archeology')
        ,   ('BB', 'Business')
        ,   ('DD', 'Doctor')
        ,   ('EE', 'English')
        ,   ('FF', 'Finance')
;

DECLARE @Image2 TABLE (Name varchar(50), CategoryID varchar(20), CategoryName varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Image2
    VALUES
            ('Aman' , 'AA'      ,   '')
        ,   ('Mani' , 'BB'      ,   '')
        ,   ('Sita' , 'AA BB'   ,   '')
        ,   ('Gita' , 'DD'      ,   '')
        ,   ('Ram'  , 'FF'      ,   '')
        ,   ('Ashi' , 'EE'      ,   '')
        ,   ('Anvi' , 'DD FF EE',   '')     
;

UPDATE I2   SET
    CategoryName = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CategoryName    FROM @Image1 I1 WHERE CHARINDEX(I1.CategoryID, I2.CategoryID)>0 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    FROM    @Image2 I2
;

SELECT * FROM @Image2;
```